# Solving ExecutionError caused by input layer

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, symbology, spatial-analyst, error-000732

I'm trying to add the symbology of an already existing layer in my folder to a the slope map being created by my Python script. I'm getting this error, however, and I don't know why.

Code:

```
def main():
    import arcpy
    from arcpy.sa import *
    arcpy.CheckOutExtension("Spatial")
    arcpy.env.workspace = "C:\\Users\\user\\OneDrive\\Documents\\ArcGIS\\ArcMap_Folder"
    inRaster = "USGS_13_n37w082_20220512.tif"

    outSlope = Slope(inRaster, "PERCENT_RISE")
    outSlope.save("C:\\Users\\user\\OneDrive\\Documents\\ArcGIS\\ArcMap_Folder\\slope2.tif")

    myRemapRange = RemapRange([[0, 3.99, 1], [4, 9.99, 2], [10, 15.99, 3], [16, 30.99, 4], [31, 60.99, 5], [61, 999999, 6]])
    outReclassRR = Reclassify(outSlope, "VALUE", myRemapRange,"NODATA" )
    outReclassRR.save("C:\\Users\\user\\OneDrive\\Documents\\ArcGIS\\ArcMap_Folder\\reclass2.tif")
    arcpy.management.MakeRasterLayer(outReclassRR, "outReclassRR_layer")
    arcpy.management.ApplySymbologyFromLayer(outReclassRR, "reclass_copy.lyr")
    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Error:

```
Runtime error  Traceback (most recent call last):   File "<string>", line 20, in <module>   File "<string>", line 16, in main   File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.8\arcpy\arcpy\management.py", line 6944, in ApplySymbologyFromLayer     raise e ExecuteError: ERROR 000732: Input Layer: Dataset C:\Users\darel\OneDrive\Documents\ArcGIS\ArcMap_Folder\reclass2.tif does not exist or is not supported ERROR 000968: The symbol layer does not match the input layer
```

I'm using ArcMap,.

Comment: The error message says "...The symbol layer does not match the input layer", I suspect your raster is not matching what ever is in your layer file `reclass_copy.lyr`? You are not showing us this so no one can comment.

Comment: @Hornbydd I figured it out. In the arcpy.management.ApplySymbologyFromLayer(outReclassRR, "reclass_copy.lyr") I was passing in a variable, instead of another .lyr file. I should have been passing the outReclassRR_layer .lyr file created from arcpy.management.MakeRasterLayer(outReclassRR, "outReclassRR_layer"). Now the code works properly. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

So I figured out that the problem was that I was passing in `"outReclassRR"` in the `arcpy.management.ApplySymbologyFromLayer()` function instead of `"outReclass_layer"` which was created from `arcpy.management.MakeRasterLayer(outReclassRR, "outReclassRR_layer")`.

Now both are being passed as .lyr files and the code is working properly.